# Select random line and output it

Tags: c#, discord

I'm in the process of making a discord bot, I was wondering how I could make a command that would select a random line of text and output it?

I would like to have a command that works similarly to this. Also,I know the basics of C#

```
Commands[ "Joke" ] = {
  oplevel:0,
  allowed_channels: 'all',
  allowed_servers: 'all',
  cooldown: 'none',
  fn: function( bot, params, msg, msgServer, serverRoles, authorRoles ) {
    var answers = [];
    answers.push({
      message: "Q: What does a dum call a dumpster? A: Bed and Breakfast"
    })
    answers.push({
      message: Q: What did the doughnut say to the loaf of bread? A: If I had that much dough, I wouldn't be hanging around this hole."
    })

    answers.push({
      message: "What does a dum call a dumpster. Bed and Breakfast"
    })
    answers.push({
      message: "Q: What did the doughnut say to the loaf of bread? A: If I had that much dough, I wouldn't be hanging around this hole."
    })
    answers.push({
      message: "Q: What do you call cheese that isnt yours? A: Nacho cheese"
    })
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. This site is not a code-writing service and is not meant for delivering complete solutions. Users are expected to show some effort and code whilst SO is here to help you solve specific programming problems along the way. Have you tried anything already? Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
int index = random.Next(answers.Count);
var answer = answers[index];
return answer;
```